# How to enforce shoes removal in a lobby/house?

Tags: design, social-interfaces, architecture

I just moved to a new flat, and I've a personal habit of removing my shoes when entering my flat, similar to the custom in some Asian cultures. This is in order to keep the house clean, and feel the ground with my feet :)

My previous flat had a smaller and less open hallway, so that it was helping to enforce this rule even to guests. On the contrary, the new hallway is bigger and open to the living room and corridor. So there is a lack of guidance here, and people can spread everywhere.

### Context

I live in a French city, and many of my guests are familiar with Japanese culture, at least peripherally through things like anime, manga and games. I'm keen to think that either living in a city doesn't entice people to remove their shoes, or that the small hallways don't help either once people have already entered the flat.

### Question

How can I design my lobby/entrance so people are aware that removing shoes is requested?

**N.B.:** I'm living in Europe where there is no such etiquette.

Comment: where in Europe are you? I always thought this was a European vs. American thing, that in Europe we do take off our shoes whilst in America they don't. 
Certainly in the UK and Sweden it is firm practice to take off your shoes when you go in most peoples houses.

Comment: wear really bright socks so that people notice that you're not wearing shoes when you open the door?

Comment: @icc97 already doing that, but never for this purpose. I will experiment on this :)

Comment: While I like the question, and love all questions that don't deal directly with computer interfaces, I have to question whether this is really on topic. It seems like it would fit better on http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: When people insist on no shoes, I get really annoyed if I wasn't warned in advance. Walking in bare feet or unsupportive shoes causes pain fairly quickly. If I know, I can bring a pair of sneakers that have never been worn outdoors. If I don't know, I either have to suffer, or just sit down my entire visit.

Comment: There are various medical conditions in which it could be beneficial for people to always where shoes especially if they have orthotics. The global issue which needs to be solved is informing people before they come over rather than at the door.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus one solution to this could be to have a supply of shoe covers/overshoes for those who can't remove their shoes

Comment: @Midas Genius! I like it!

Comment: Do you allow people changing into different shoes ?

Comment: @theotherone, I was thinking the same thing. Over here the expectation is to remove your shoes and walking into someone's house wearing shoes would be considered extremely rude. The obvious exception is when the host tells you not to take them off.

Comment: Please, specify where from Europe you are. I've **never** worn shoes inside an apparment, not even on a visit, and not even in France. All my French hosts understood my preference of not wearing shoes inside (it's always been friends to whom I could explain things).

Comment: @copper.hat In the case of the UK it's probably dependant on the location. In the west country removing your shoes is the norm, it might be different in London or up north or you've only been to a handful of UK households. Also the reason for your visit has an impact. Asking a business visitor (e.g. salesperson, lawyer, plumber) to remove their shoes is uncommon, typically only friends and family are asked to remove their shoes.

Comment: @Pharap well I don't see the point of asking friend to remove shoes if you don't do the same with business visitors.

Comment: @theotherone - I suppose it depends on where you are in the US. I'm from the Midwest and I've never been to a house where I've felt comfortable keeping my shoes on, it just seems rude.

Comment: @DangerZone On the east coast (Virginia), I'm rarely ever asked to take off my shoes. Although if the person has carpeting that looks easily dirtied I do it anyway.

Comment: *" I'm living in Europe were there is no such etiquette."* - this is strange, because I also live in Europe and in all the homes I visited the guests were expected to take their shoes off. Is France an exception?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez It's a cultural thing. That and it would be silly to ask a manual worker (e.g. a plumber) to remove their shoes if they have to keep putting them back on again every time they need to go back to the van for another tool.

Comment: I always leave all my shoes in the entrance area, guests see me take off shoes so they need to do it too.

Comment: Grrmany here. We take our shoes off

Comment: Why is everyone acting like "Europe" is some big homogeneous place with uniform cultural customs? This is crazy. You know there are hundreds of millions of people living here, right? At least in my part of France, removing shoes is not the norm, but it's not unusual for a host to ask people to remove their shoes either (and people typically comply without complaint).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi To be fair, that is how most of us think of the US as well. :)

Comment: @Peter The US is much more homogeneous than Europe. Same language, same history, same money, same government, same TV shows, same movies, same books...

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's true. But it's not quite as homogenous as we sometimes think.

Comment: Living in London in the UK, we remove our shoes in our home although many friends do not in theirs. The pile of shoes by our front door, and us in our socks, always seems sufficient to let visitors know to remove their shoes.

Comment: I've never seen an English person in London remove their shoes. On the other hand Non-English people remove them without asking most of the time.

Comment: Kevin McAllister in the film _Home Alone_ enforced his home's no-shoe policy by coating his floor in tar, but that approach would be better suited for lifehacks.stackexchange.com...

Comment: It sounds to me like you should have signs directing guests to go into the living room first. There you could have a shoe rack and a bench or a couple of tabourets for people to sit on while they're taking them off. If you're having a party where guests could arrive in large numbers at the same time, that's more difficult because the overflow would naturally go into other rooms. For larger parties, myself I will move furniture to direct the flow of traffic and prevent guests going into areas where they're not supposed to go. But also I'll give up on the no-shoe requirement during those events.

Comment: This Englishman, living in London, has almost never been asked to remove shoes.

Comment: @Pharap: here in Western Canada, every manual worker that enters the house removes his/her shoes. And it makes sense: why would the fact that they are working allow them to ruin your carpet?

Comment: Put a security guard by the door and have him shoot anybody who doesn't take off their shoes. [That's what "enforce" means.]

Comment: it's not usual at all in southern europe, where the climate is mild / calid and it's uncommon to have mud / water / wathever and where wooden floors are very rare.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk we had a party the weekend after I asked the question and the first persons to come in removed their shoes and others followed their example.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Canada is special though. In some places in Canada people still don't lock their doors and there are places where the streets are free of litter.

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez, That's true enough. People follow by example. I know I do. Even if I initially skip the shoe removal area, I will backtrack if I can't find anyone else wearing shoes.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: here (Germany) workers are expected to keep their shoes on (often safety shoes, btw.) - and I'd guess a plumber's accident insurance would make a big stink if they hurt themselves dropping a tool on their toes and it turns out they didn't wear appropriate shoes. So I guess the dominant question here would be: why should the fact that you have a carpet impose on them higher working hazards?

Answer (score 79):

## Instruct

Having something like [this doormat](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=doormat%20please%20remove%20your%20shoes&num=30&safe=strict&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicu--Gy-XLAhWHthoKHZHnCSwQ_AUIBygB&biw=1600&bih=799#imgrc=W7OW1eSord-FEM%3A) *outside* your front door will **'permission prime'** your guests on your expectations about shoe removal.

[image]

## Reinforce

Having your shoes on a shoe-rack on the inside of your flat will further **reinforce** your expectation.

[image]

Comment: In India, we have signboards for the same. I doubt anybody will notice this on a doormat.

Comment: I like the shoe-rack idea, as it offer people a solution to remove their shoes.

Comment: We should set expectations for the OP. It is *not* a normal custom, and therefore the OP will find themselves having to ask folks often. Most folks won't mind once asked, but it may never cross their mind otherwise. Also keep in mind how dreadfully inconvenient this can be for some folks, depending on what they are wearing, especially if they are not staying long.

Comment: In addition, hardwood floors have a habit of eating through people's socks... keep this in mind and provide plenty of area rugs so that you don't damage your guest's socks.

Comment: I personally would not use a sign as I would be ridiculed mercilessly by my friends for having it. Mostly because 'signs' are read as 'nags'. I usually ask and people remember. Non-verbally the 'Reinforce' is similar to what I do. I have a pile of shoes at the front door as a reminder. Though shoe racks hide shoes, and I want people to know.

Comment: ^ @jmathew is on the right track. Signs are good, if you are okay with being perceived as uptight. A direct visual reinforcement (a pile of shoes in the entry) is nearly as good and not as pushy. Putting the shoes in a rack of some type will create a barrier: **people would rather just toss their shoes off on a mat**.

Comment: @plainclothes Or alternatively you could see it as the shoerack shows visitors that the owner of the house is providing them with a safe place in which to put their shoes after they have been removed. If I were someone who cared very much about my shoes I wouldn't want them to be lumped in a heap among a load of other (potentially dirty) shoes.

Comment: I was going to say something along the lines of 'put up a "take your goddamn shoes off" sign', but your idea is far less blunt.

Comment: I think you (and the linked article) don't quite understand what priming is. A mat that says 'take of your shoes' is quite direct and explicit, as is a coupon-code field.

Comment: @SnakeDoc I suspect if this is a normal custom or not depends on where you live.  The harsher your winters are, the more likely it's a normal custom.  In Chicago most people remove their shoes before going inside.

Comment: @PixelSnader Not sure what linked article you're referencing, but isn't the whole point of this answer "this mat primes your guests"?

Comment: @plainclothes. the article they removed 3 hours ago; http://conversionxl.com/how-to-use-priming-to-improve-ux . And yes, the point of this answer is "this mat primes your guests" - but that mat isn't priming because the message is explicit; it's directly instructing the reader to do something. Primes are implicit, or even subconscious.

Comment: ^ fussy semantic arguments are the primary reason so many good product people don't come here 

Comment: @PixelSnader did comment earlier but may have deleted by accident. I used the 'prime' analogy referring to 'permission priming', like you get in app onboarding. I took your point, so I removed the reference. Cheers.

Comment: @plainclothes if you have a more [casual sign](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=aloha+remove+your+shoes&iax=1&ia=images) it may help with being perceived as uptight.

Comment: @plainclothes I'd rather have people leave because they can't see past 'fussy' arguments, than stay and get incorrect answers.

Comment: In the spirit of community building ... ( ¬ _ ¬ )

Comment: Here are some cuter signs: https://www.google.com/search?q=cute+sign+for+removing+the+shoes&source=lnms&tbm=isch (although the parent will obviously need to redo the search in French).

Comment: @plainclothes in the spirit of not spreading misinformation. A wrong story told a lot does more harm than a right story not told.

Comment: @PixelSnader realizing now that we're reading this differently. I saw "Please remove your shoes [when you get in the house]" assuming it was an outdoor mat. That's what I'd call "forceful" priming. I'm guessing you read it as an indoor mat with immediate instructions. Okay, that's enough vocab time for me.

Comment: @plainclothes doesn't matter where the mat is. The instructions are still direct. A simpler example: "our burger is only 1.95 this week" is priming. "buy our burger at the next gas station" isn't, and neither is this mat.

Comment: I tried. I really tried. 

Comment: +1. Also a bench to sit while you remove your shoes and slippers to wear makes it nicer.

Comment: @Logan I prefer your idea, there's much better signs when you search for ['take off your damn shoes'](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sa=1&q=take+off+your+damn+shoes). Might not work so well with the in-laws though.

Answer (score 46):

It is not uncommon to take your shoes off in Europe (at least in the UK and Belgium where I've lived).

However, just sticking up a sign might be seen as rude / impersonal. If all else fails it's best just to ask people to take their shoes off. Assuming that your place is clean their shouldn't be any objections (unless they've got hole in their socks).

1. As I commented, **just wearing socks should often be enough** (you could A/B test with colour/brightness for impact :)). Last week I was looking around a house to buy and we noticed that the owners weren't wearing shoes, so we automatically apologised and took our shoes off. So hopefully attentive guests should notice that you're not wearing shoes.
2. You can **line up your shoes that you've taken off by the door** so that people notice the shoes. Something that is by the door is something that is typically taken off as you enter. People will be looking around at your hallway as they enter so they should spot them. You can also have a shoe rack by the door with empty slots for them to put their shoes in.
3. you could actually **offer people (machine washable) slippers** as I believe it is custom in Japan to do.

   [image]
   This kind of makes something interesting about it - i.e.

   > "we like to do things Japanese style here"

   rather than

   > "we're foot cleanliness fetishists"

   This also might avoid the problem of people having holes in their socks as they can just hide them inside the slippers.
4. **Hard floors** also help as the difference in noise between you in socks / slippers vs the loudness of shoes should be noticeable.
5. If you're having a party, you might have to **be blunt and just ask people**, hopefully the pile of shoes at the door from all the guests should be a clue to the later arrivals.
6. Also it seems that the common Japanese area where you remove your shoes is the ['genkan'](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2001.html). If you can make you're entrance look like that it should help even more. If you can add Japanese artwork to the walls that should also help.

[image]

Comment: Where in Europe would people ignore a request to remove their shoes, if asked to do so? Here in Germany, it would be considered extremely rude of a guest to not respect that wish...

Comment: @rackandboneman yes I agree - the only reason I thought people might be hesitant is if people weren't expecting it and they have holes in their socks or something. But I think the OP ideally doesn't want to have to ask everyone.

Comment: @rackandboneman I've clarified my opening sentences, hopefully that makes more sense as to what I mean

Comment: offering slippers can have hygiene drawback, i.e. the need to wash slippers very regularly in order to prevent mycosis spread.

Comment: Machine Washable slippers? http://www.amazon.com/Sunshine-Code-Cotton-Washable-Slippers/dp/B0162X3KM8

Comment: Most people should be wearing socks and mycosis is spread mostly through bare skin contact. This could be a reason for buying open toed slippers to lower the areas where spores could grow. But to transfer the spores they would have to go through the socks of one person remain on the slipper and then go back through the socks of the next person. But on top of this you don't really mind if peoeple don't wear the slippers it's just a way of suggesting for people to take off their shoes.

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez in the US, footwear rental establishments (bowling alleys, skating rinks, etc) solve this with antifungal spray, a similar approach would work here and be less resource intensive than full washing.

Comment: @JeffMeden I had thought of this - but I then just have this comic image in my head of the OP walking to the door in his bowling alley employee uniform asking for your shoes and then giving you an oversized pair of slippery shoes. Then when it's time to leave taking the shoes back spraying them like crazy wtih fungicide spray putting them back in the rack.

Comment: @icc97 you obviously would wait until they leave to kill off all their foot fungus... ;-)

Comment: @JeffMeden I would actually want to *see* them spray the slippers *before* I put them on (DO NOT google "foot fungus" or "foot disease" to find out why). I actually saw a foot doctor's office that had a sign saying "please remove dirty footwear" -  that was not going to happen, rude or not. I'd prefer something like these [disposable shoe covers](http://www.amazon.com/Disposable-Overshoes-Kwik-Kover-Production/dp/B0057VBSA8) instead of old "guest slippers" - both if I were a guest visiting someone's house, and for people visiting my house (who knows what's really on other people's feet)

Comment: @Xen2050 I have seen these blue plastic bag overshoes used for e.g. gyms, but they're so ugly and impersonal to have in your own house. A slightly nicer alternative is these [disposable hotel slippers](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-Quality-Disposable-Hotel-Guest-Slippers_874158258.html) which seem reasonable. But as I [commented earlier](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/91980/how-to-enforce-shoes-removal-in-a-lobby-house/91992?noredirect=1#comment147159_91992) - if you don't want to wear the slippers then you don't need to, it is just catering for the people who do.

Comment: @rackandboneman: (Germany as well) yes ignoring the request to take off shoes is rude. OTOH, I grew up with the rule that it is polite to ask your visitors to keep on their shoes, or to warn them beforehand to bring their own house shoes/slippers. And that it is super impolite when asking your visitors to take off their shoes  not to provide house shoes/slippers for them. And in Italy I learned that taking off your shoes as a visitor is impolite.

Answer (score 22):

Of course you can ask people, and of course you can put up a sign, but this is a UX question, not a lifestyle/etiquette question. In an interaction design we wouldn't be happy putting up signs, or telling people how to behave: we want an environment that makes the desired behaviour automatic.

I can't think of any any way to force this absolutely, but I think we can get pretty close:

- Clearly delineate the hallway (where shoes are allowed) and the living room (no shoes)
- Cover your living room with deep, luxurious carpet. Keep this extremely clean.
- **Fill your hallway with wet mud.** Make sure to spray it with water just before the guests arrive, so they really sink into it.

It's quite a length to go to, but short of pets and very absent-minded children, I can't think of anybody who would not be acutely aware of how dirty their feet are and looking around for at least a mat to wipe them. Of course, you do *not provide a mat*, but you do offer a little stool to sit down on, take your shoes off, and place them in a cabinet.

We can use this bacic idea and make it less extreme (and a little less effective). For instance, you could tile your hallway with the exact same paving stones they have just outside your door. This still reminds visitors that they are in a shoe-zone. The important thing, again, is not to offer a mat. Don't give them any way to undirty their shoes and offer anything they need to take them off.

Further tips:

- Place extremely dirty shoes in their eyeline to reinforce the idea that shoes are dirty.
- Place little slippers just over the threshold to reinforce the idea, and make it inviting.
- Have a pair of flip-flops or sandals that you put on for entering the hallway, so that the rule goes both ways: no socks in the hallway, no shoes in the living room.

I should note that if you actually do this people will think you are mad and stop visiting anyway, but if you really want to nudge people, this should be the most effective method.

Comment: +1 - I think this is a perfect example of what the UX people constantly blather about but rarely actually manage: The _intuitive user interface_.

Comment: Joined UX just to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 11):

### Start with subtle clues, slowly becoming more direct.

As is commonly advised to writers; **show, don't tell.**

People like making decisions on their own, but they also generally want to make others feel good. And especially in new environments and situations, we mimic. It's all about gradually going from subliminal cues to explicitly stating the intended outcome.

---

### 1 - Take off your own shoes.

If you're bringing guests to your home, take off your shoes first, and then your coat after. This gives your guests the time to see that you're taking your shoes off, and they can follow suit. People generally take off their coats first and then their shoes, so it might feel weird to do this order, but it also draws extra attention to the act.

If you're already at home wearing nothing but socks (well, hopefully a *bit* more..) you can't really take off your shoes, so skip this bit.

---

### 2 - Have a place for the shoes

Like others mentioned, having a shoe rack would be very beneficial. People see they that shoes are kept near the door, so they're likely put on/off near the door. They can then infer that they should do something with their shoes after using the door. As they're currently wearing shoes, the logical option is to take them off.

---

### 3 - Suggest where they can put their shoes

If you're not sure they've seen the rack, or if they're not preparing to take off their shoes, point the rack out, in a non-intrusive way.

*"The coatrack is there, and you can put your shoes underneath"*

This way they definitely know where to put their shoes if they decide to take them off. You're implying a link between hanging up a coat and taking off shoes. They're currently taking off coats, so perhaps take off the shoes too?

The phrasing here is important. When you say "you can do X" it still leaves the decision up to the guest. You're not telling them to do X, you're assuming they want to do X, and helping them do it. it's supportive and guiding, not instructive and authoritarian.

---

### 4 - Outright ask them. But be kind.

When they don't get any of the clues, ask them if they want to take of their shoes. Don't tell, ask. "would you mind taking off your shoes? I like to keep the house clean." It's still not authoritarian, but a request, still technically leaving the choice with your guest. But if they're nice people, they'll comply.

Because they're visiting your house, they'll likely act nice. They're probably there to connect closer with you, which doesn't work if they frustrate you. Second, it's your house, your rules, at least that's the social contract in most cultures.

---

### 5 - Put your foot down.

Oy bruv take them trainers off before I knock you in the gabber. I'mma screw you right up mate, loose the boots. Respect my authoritah!

[image]

<sub>I  kid, I kid. Don't actually get aggressive.</sub>

Comment: There's not nearly enough photos in this answer. Please extend it.

Answer (score 5):

Here in the UK many expect shoes to come off at the door and visitors will ask if they should remove them. We change from shoes to slippers as soon as we get home. We have an area in our entrance with a Bench so everyone can sit and easily remove shoes.
I have found that it's best to be open and keep things simple. If people don't ask them we just say that we don't wear shoes in the house and could they please take them off.
Guest slippers would not work here, and I wouldn't wear them when visiting. We advise people that we are a shoes off house and ask they bring slippers or socks.
Taking shoes off is second nature for me but not everyone was brought up to do it . i can't imagine wearing shoes in the house or on someone's lovely carpets.

Comment: While I agree with this, I reckomend refraining from using the wording "*We* don't wear shoes in *this house*.", it comes across as being cold/creepy. Something like "Would you mind taking your shoes off?" is much more inviting.

Comment: It's true, in the UK people just ask, and people do it. We're not a shoes off house (lived too long in dodgy rented places where the floor threatens you, not vice versa that it became a habit). But I'd not blink if someone asked me to take them off or not to step on this or that in shoes. Maybe it's 50/50? For a country which is almost never direct in anything, it's just occurred to me that this is quite remarkable.

Comment: @Pharap The answer says "We don't wear shoes in the house", not "... in this house." I still prefer your phrasing, but "We don't wear shoes in the house" sounds a lot less obnoxious to my (British) ears than "We don't wear shoes in this house."

Comment: I can't imagine "We don't wear shoes in this house" being said in anything but a [Hyacinth Bucket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Keeping_Up_Appearances_characters#Hyacinth_Bucket) voice

Comment: @DavidRicherby Still sounds a bit like something Hyacinth Bucket might say. The use of "we" is too easily misconstrued as uninviting or as suggesting a clear division between 'we' and 'you'. Also you're not technically asking them to take their shoes off, you're attempting to imply that they should remove their shoes, which may go over some people's heads or lead some c̶h̶e̶e̶k̶y̶ ̶s̶o̶d̶s̶ people to pretend they don't understand what you're trying to imply.

Comment: Grow up man. You are talking about the distinction between two identical phrases. In my experience people really don't give a monkeys between this and the. If some get uptight about such triviality then there really is something wrong with them. Life's too short to worry about monosyllabics

Comment: @user568458 It's pronounced *bōˈkā* (*bouquet* ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Why not just ask your guests to take off their shoes as they come in?

- Unlike a sign, it can't be interpreted as being pushy. At least in my experience, I've never felt that someone asking me to take off my shoes is being uptight, and I've never seen or heard of someone being annoyed by being asked to take off their shoes.
- I don't think I would pick up the hint if you had a shoe rack or were wearing brightly colored socks. Instead of thinking, "I should put my shoes in the rack," or, "I should be in socks myself," I would think, "Édouard Lopez uses a shoe rack and likes to wear brightly colored socks. Good for him, and I'll do what I'm comfortable with."
- Asking people to take off their shoes is direct, polite, and impossible to misinterpret.

There really isn't any UI magic in this answer. But I think maybe the simplest answer is best in this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Set a white, clean blanket in the floor, and leave your shoes (a couple pairs) just before stepping on it as a demonstration.
This should make your visitors worry about stepping on such a clean surface and imagine the solution.
Anyway, be ready to handle cases of people that will not understand without getting upset.

Comment: Wow, this is great.  A bright white mat will draw the eye in contrast to the (maybe) cluttered, (typically) dark surroundings of an entry.  Put a couple pairs of shoes on it like "salting" a tip jar.  Have a place to sit down *before* crossing the great white barrier.  Heck, turn a solid white hallway runner sideways to really drive home the boundary of cleanliness concept.

Answer (score 4):

As I can't comment, I had to answer as a solution.

As a French, I would also suggest to just tell people right away if you don't see them taking their shoes off as some people can miss cues, as Alex has suggested.

And you can be pretty blunt about it. While Pharap is right that you can be more engaging, you can also be very direct with French people (1) we don't consider that as rude, I am living in the UK at the moment and I am well aware that directness can be perceived as rude, but not particularly by most in France.

We can perceive things as rude, but: 'Pourriez-vous retirer vos chaussures, s'il vous plait' should not. And thanks them afterwards. (2)

Oddly, I would **personally** perceive the sign/doormat proposed by Midas as rude. I would not mind it too much if you are a teacher or a health worker or such a profession that you are used to give orders to people all the time (as I would see that as a by-product of your profession, but then I would also consider that you are a pretty rigid person or you have a weird sense of humour).

BTW, it is pretty common in France to not wear shoes at home - that is the case of most of my friends living in flats. However, the guest policy can be a little bit more flexible. In houses, it is a little bit more fuzzy as well. Most of the newer constructions are usually divided into a 'day' and a 'night' part. And a lot of people (but not all) would allow their guests to keep their shoes on as long as the guests stay in the day part.

This said, not wearing shoes yourself, should be a great cue by itself. Having some shoes in the entrance and slippers will also be another cue. If you are fond of carpet, one with longer threads and with light tones should bring 80% of your guests ask you if you want them to take their shoes off.

One main reason, that some people might try to play dumb would be that they might be ashamed of showing their feet or socks. If you have slippers around that should not be a problem anymore.

If you have wooden floor, you can also have 'patins' (I tried to find an English equivalent but didn't manage to). You usually see this in old fashion houses, but people should recognise them right away [image: patin]

Basically, you keep your shoes, but you need to keep them on those 'patins'. I find them very annoying and I usually ask if I can take my shoes off and sometimes I am answered by the host that they prefer me to keep the shoes and the patins.

---

(1) However, they would be some categories of people that as a French you wouldn't really ask to take their shoes off if you don't already have a close relationship: these people would include older people, particularly the parents and grand-parents of your girlfriend/boyfriend, your boss and their family. Nonetheless, most of them would propose themselves to take their shoes off.

(2) As a rule of thumb, if you try to be nice, have an engaging tone and don't forget to say 'Bonjour/Bonsoir', 'S'il vous/te plait' et 'Merci' you should not be perceived as rude. (This is also true for cafés, restaurants or markets.)

Comment: What are "patins"? Google (images) seems to think they're rollerblades. Are they like coasters for your feet, so you have to "shuffle" around so they don't get left behind? Or are they like soft cloth overshoes, to go in between your shoes and the floors, kind of like a "whole shoe sock"?

Comment: @Xen2050 so 'patins' can be rollerblades but they also can indeed be coasters for you feet as you said and you have to shuffle them. :(  They look like slippers without the top part. You can't "wear" them, you can just push them around. The mother of one of my friends has this habit of waxing her living room parquet every Saturday, so if it happened that I was visiting that day I was always requested to use those: for several reasons: 1) To avoid to dirty my socks if there was wax left,2) to not slip 3) to not dirty their parquet with my shoes, and 4) to help with the polishing process.

Answer (score 1):

My home is a shoe-free zone as well.  Our family uses a shoe rack and our guests typically leave their shoes in a pile next to whatever shoes we used that day.

Whenever we'll having groups of people over we tell them in advance, "...oh and by the way we're a shoe-free home just so you're not thrown off we when you see the big pile of shoes by the door".

Answer (score 1):

I'd give a try of placing a shoe cabinet straight against the door (of the hallway size allows that, of course) so that you'd have to pass by its side on entrance.

In this case, the shoe cabinet would act as a barrier on the entry and would naturally remind of itself by stopping the natural pathway course.